# Unable to store date and timestamp values in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, date, timestamp

I have  date and timestamp fields in mysql table.

```
$timeString="Thu Jul 26 22:45:09 +0000 2012";

$time=strtotime($timeString);

$date=date('Y-m-d', $timeString);
```

When I execute the query it storing the following values:

date 0000-00-00
time 0000-00-00 00:00:00

Can anyone fix my problem.

Comment: You don't show your query text. I suggest you echo the sql statement (the actual SQL text that is going to be sent to the database.) That should reveal the problem.

Answer (score 6):

you're trying to build your date from `$timestring` (the string) instead of `$time`(the timestamp )

try:

```
$timeString="Thu Jul 26 22:45:09 +0000 2012";

$time=strtotime($timeString);

$date=date('Y-m-d', $time);
```

you should enable php warnings in your development environment.
date would have told you :)

> date() expects parameter 2 to be long, string given

Answer (score 0):

```
$date = new DateTime('Thu Jul 26 22:45:09 +0000 2012');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```